# JTable how to change BackGround Color

Tags: java, swing, jtable, gradient, jviewport

I inspired by `MeBigFatGuy` interesting [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195959/swing-jtable-event-when-row-is-visible-or-when-scrolled-to-the-bottom), in this conection I have very specific question about `Graphisc2D`, how to change `BackGround Color` by depends if is `JTables Row` visible in the `JViewPort`,

1) if `1st. & last JTables Row` will be visible in the `JViewPort`, then BackGround would be colored to the `Color.red`

2) if `1st. & last JTables Row` will not be visible in the `JViewPort`, then `BackGround` would be colored to the `Color.whatever`

[image]

from [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.RepaintManager;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

/*
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249278/
how-to-disable-the-default-painting-behaviour-of-wheel-scroll-event-on-jscrollpan
 *
and
 *
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195959/
swing-jtable-event-when-row-is-visible-or-when-scrolled-to-the-bottom
 */
public class ViewPortFlickering {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("Table");
    private JViewport viewport = new JViewport();
    private Rectangle RECT = new Rectangle();
    private Rectangle RECT1 = new Rectangle();
    private JTable table = new JTable(50, 3);
    private javax.swing.Timer timer;
    private int count = 0;

    public ViewPortFlickering() {
        GradientViewPort tableViewPort = new GradientViewPort(table);
        viewport = tableViewPort.getViewport();
        viewport.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                RECT = table.getCellRect(0, 0, true);
                RECT1 = table.getCellRect(table.getRowCount() - 1, 0, true);
                Rectangle viewRect = viewport.getViewRect();
                if (viewRect.intersects(RECT)) {
                    System.out.println("Visible RECT -> " + RECT);
                } else if (viewRect.intersects(RECT1)) {
                    System.out.println("Visible RECT1 -> " + RECT1);
                } else {
                    //
                }
            }
        });
        frame.add(tableViewPort);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 300));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocation(50, 100);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        RepaintManager.setCurrentManager(new RepaintManager() {

            @Override
            public void addDirtyRegion(JComponent c, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
                Container con = c.getParent();
                while (con instanceof JComponent) {
                    if (!con.isVisible()) {
                        return;
                    }
                    if (con instanceof GradientViewPort) {
                        c = (JComponent) con;
                        x = 0;
                        y = 0;
                        w = con.getWidth();
                        h = con.getHeight();
                    }
                    con = con.getParent();
                }
                super.addDirtyRegion(c, x, y, w, h);
            }
        });
        frame.setVisible(true);
        start();
    }

    private void start() {
        timer = new javax.swing.Timer(100, updateCol());
        timer.start();
    }

    public Action updateCol() {
        return new AbstractAction("text load action") {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                System.out.println("updating row " + (count + 1));
                TableModel model = table.getModel();
                int cols = model.getColumnCount();
                int row = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                    row = count;
                    table.changeSelection(row, 0, false, false);
                    timer.setDelay(100);
                    Object value = "row " + (count + 1) + " item " + (j + 1);
                    model.setValueAt(value, count, j);
                }
                count++;
                if (count >= table.getRowCount()) {
                    timer.stop();
                    table.changeSelection(0, 0, false, false);
                    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            table.clearSelection();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ViewPortFlickering viewPortFlickering = new ViewPortFlickering();
            }
        });
    }
}

class GradientViewPort extends JScrollPane {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final int h = 50;
    private BufferedImage img = null;
    private BufferedImage shadow = new BufferedImage(1, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    private JViewport viewPort;

    public GradientViewPort(JComponent com) {
        super(com);
        viewPort = this.getViewport();
        viewPort.setScrollMode(JViewport.BLIT_SCROLL_MODE);
        viewPort.setScrollMode(JViewport.BACKINGSTORE_SCROLL_MODE);
        viewPort.setScrollMode(JViewport.SIMPLE_SCROLL_MODE);
        Graphics2D g2 = shadow.createGraphics();
        g2.setPaint(new Color(250, 150, 150));
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, 1, h);
        g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.DstIn);
        g2.setPaint(new GradientPaint(0, 0, new Color(0, 0, 0, 0f), 0, h,
                new Color(0.5f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.5f)));
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, 1, h);
        g2.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        if (img == null || img.getWidth() != getWidth() || img.getHeight() != getHeight()) {
            img = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        }
        Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
        super.paint(g2);
        Rectangle bounds = getViewport().getVisibleRect();
        g2.scale(bounds.getWidth(), -1);
        int y = (getColumnHeader() == null) ? 0 : getColumnHeader().getHeight();
        g2.drawImage(shadow, bounds.x, -bounds.y - y - h, null);
        g2.scale(1, -1);
        g2.drawImage(shadow, bounds.x, bounds.y + bounds.height - h + y, null);
        g2.dispose();
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question. If you only want the first/last rows to be a different color, then just use the "Table Row Renderering" approach you've seen from my blog. They will only be renderered when they are visible in the viewport.

Comment: @camickr I'm not able to change GradientPaint (simple way) to the another Color, depends of that if some JTable's Row is/isn't visible in the JViewPort

Comment: RECT ? please learn java naming conventions and stick to them ;-)

Comment: curious: why? a) overriding paint b) custom repaintManager?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

since I search for different suggestion I closed this question with my original knowledges about Graphics

[image]
[image]
[image]

based on code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
//import java.awt.image.ColorModel; // I don't know how to use that
//import java.awt.image.SampleModel;// I don't know how to use that
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.RepaintManager;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class ViewPortFlickeringOriginal {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("Table");
    private JViewport viewport = new JViewport();
    private Rectangle RECT = new Rectangle();
    private Rectangle RECT1 = new Rectangle();
    private JTable table = new JTable(50, 3);
    private javax.swing.Timer timer;
    private int count = 0;
    private boolean topOrBottom = false;
    private GradientViewPortOriginal tableViewPort;

    public ViewPortFlickeringOriginal() {
        tableViewPort = new GradientViewPortOriginal(table);
        viewport = tableViewPort.getViewport();
        viewport.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                if (tableViewPort.bolStart) {
                    RECT = table.getCellRect(0, 0, true);
                    RECT1 = table.getCellRect(table.getRowCount() - 1, 0, true);
                    Rectangle viewRect = viewport.getViewRect();
                    if (viewRect.intersects(RECT)) {
                        System.out.println("Visible RECT -> " + RECT);
                        tableViewPort.paintBackGround(new Color(250, 150, 150));
                    } else if (viewRect.intersects(RECT1)) {
                        System.out.println("Visible RECT1 -> " + RECT1);
                        tableViewPort.paintBackGround(new Color(150, 250, 150));
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Visible RECT1 -> ???? ");
                        tableViewPort.paintBackGround(new Color(150, 150, 250));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        frame.add(tableViewPort);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 300));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocation(50, 100);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        RepaintManager.setCurrentManager(new RepaintManager() {

            @Override
            public void addDirtyRegion(JComponent c, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
                Container con = c.getParent();
                while (con instanceof JComponent) {
                    if (!con.isVisible()) {
                        return;
                    }
                    if (con instanceof GradientViewPortOriginal) {
                        c = (JComponent) con;
                        x = 0;
                        y = 0;
                        w = con.getWidth();
                        h = con.getHeight();
                    }
                    con = con.getParent();
                }
                super.addDirtyRegion(c, x, y, w, h);
            }
        });
        frame.setVisible(true);
        start();
    }

    private void start() {
        timer = new javax.swing.Timer(100, updateCol());
        timer.start();
    }

    public Action updateCol() {
        return new AbstractAction("text load action") {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                System.out.println("updating row " + (count + 1));
                TableModel model = table.getModel();
                int cols = model.getColumnCount();
                int row = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                    row = count;
                    table.changeSelection(row, 0, false, false);
                    timer.setDelay(100);
                    Object value = "row " + (count + 1) + " item " + (j + 1);
                    model.setValueAt(value, count, j);
                }
                count++;
                if (count >= table.getRowCount()) {
                    timer.stop();
                    table.changeSelection(0, 0, false, false);
                    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            table.clearSelection();
                            tableViewPort.bolStart = true;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ViewPortFlickeringOriginal viewPortFlickering = new ViewPortFlickeringOriginal();
            }
        });
    }
}

class GradientViewPortOriginal extends JScrollPane {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final int h = 50;
    private BufferedImage img = null;
    private BufferedImage shadow = new BufferedImage(1, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    private JViewport viewPort;
    public boolean bolStart = false;

    public GradientViewPortOriginal(JComponent com) {
        super(com);
        viewPort = this.getViewport();
        viewPort.setScrollMode(JViewport.BLIT_SCROLL_MODE);
        viewPort.setScrollMode(JViewport.BACKINGSTORE_SCROLL_MODE);
        viewPort.setScrollMode(JViewport.SIMPLE_SCROLL_MODE);
        paintBackGround(new Color(250, 150, 150));
    }

    public void paintBackGround(Color g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = shadow.createGraphics();
        g2.setPaint(g);
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, 1, h);
        g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.DstIn);
        g2.setPaint(new GradientPaint(0, 0, new Color(0, 0, 0, 0f), 0, h,
                new Color(0.1f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.5f)));
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, 1, h);
        g2.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        if (img == null || img.getWidth() != getWidth() || img.getHeight() != getHeight()) {
            img = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        }
        Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
        super.paint(g2);
        Rectangle bounds = getViewport().getVisibleRect();
        g2.scale(bounds.getWidth(), -1);
        int y = (getColumnHeader() == null) ? 0 : getColumnHeader().getHeight();
        g2.drawImage(shadow, bounds.x, -bounds.y - y - h, null);
        g2.scale(1, -1);
        g2.drawImage(shadow, bounds.x, bounds.y + bounds.height - h + y, null);
        g2.dispose();
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: changed Colors to the Neon's based colors

Answer (score 2):

Something like this... a bit of a hack.

```
class GradientViewPort extends JScrollPane {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final int h = 50;
    private BufferedImage img = null;
    private BufferedImage imgBottom = null;
    private BufferedImage shadow = new BufferedImage(1, h,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    private BufferedImage shadowBottom = new BufferedImage(1, h,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    private JViewport viewPort;

    public GradientViewPort(JComponent com) {
        super(com);
        viewPort = this.getViewport();
        viewPort.setScrollMode(JViewport.BLIT_SCROLL_MODE);
        viewPort.setScrollMode(JViewport.BACKINGSTORE_SCROLL_MODE);
        viewPort.setScrollMode(JViewport.SIMPLE_SCROLL_MODE);
        createShadow(new Color(250, 150, 150),shadow);
        createShadow(Color.BLUE,shadowBottom);

    }

    private void createShadow(Color color, BufferedImage shadow) {
        Graphics2D g2 = shadow.createGraphics();
        g2.setPaint(color);
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, 1, h);
        g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.DstIn);
        g2.setPaint(new GradientPaint(0, 0, new Color(0, 0, 0, 0f), 0, h,
                new Color(0.5f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.5f)));
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, 1, h);
        g2.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        paintTop(g,img);
        paintBottom(g,imgBottom);
    }

    private void paintBottom(Graphics g,BufferedImage img) {
        if (img == null || img.getWidth() != getWidth()
                || img.getHeight() != getHeight()) {
            img = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(),
                    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        }
        Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
        //super.paint(g2);
        Rectangle bounds = getViewport().getVisibleRect();
        g2.scale(bounds.getWidth(), -1);
        int y = (getColumnHeader() == null) ? 0 : getColumnHeader().getHeight();
        //g2.drawImage(shadowBottom, bounds.x, -bounds.y - y - h, null);
        g2.scale(1, -1);
        g2.drawImage(shadowBottom, bounds.x, bounds.y + bounds.height - h + y, null);
        g2.dispose();
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    }

    private void paintTop(Graphics g,BufferedImage img) {
        if (img == null || img.getWidth() != getWidth()
                || img.getHeight() != getHeight()) {
            img = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(),
                    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        }
        Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
        super.paint(g2);
        Rectangle bounds = getViewport().getVisibleRect();
        g2.scale(bounds.getWidth(), -1);
        int y = (getColumnHeader() == null) ? 0 : getColumnHeader().getHeight();
        g2.drawImage(shadow, bounds.x, -bounds.y - y - h, null);
        g2.scale(1, -1);
        //g2.drawImage(shadow, bounds.x, bounds.y + bounds.height - h + y, null);
        g2.dispose();
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    }
```

EDIT fixed the code so when first and last row are in the view port the color is red when they are not the color is blue.

```
    class GradientViewPort extends JScrollPane {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final int h = 50;
    private BufferedImage imgRed = null;
    private BufferedImage imgBlue = null;
    private BufferedImage shadowRed = new BufferedImage(1, h,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    private BufferedImage shadowBlue = new BufferedImage(1, h,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    private JViewport viewPort;
    private boolean recVisible = true;

    public GradientViewPort(JComponent com) {
        super(com);
        viewPort = this.getViewport();
        viewPort.setScrollMode(JViewport.BLIT_SCROLL_MODE);
        viewPort.setScrollMode(JViewport.BACKINGSTORE_SCROLL_MODE);
        viewPort.setScrollMode(JViewport.SIMPLE_SCROLL_MODE);
        createShadow(new Color(250, 150, 150),shadowRed);
        createShadow(Color.BLUE,shadowBlue);

        final JTable table = (JTable) com;
        viewport.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                Rectangle RECT = table.getCellRect(0, 0, true);

                Rectangle viewRect = viewport.getViewRect();
                if (viewRect.intersects(RECT)) {
                    System.out.println("Visible RECT -> " + RECT);
                    recVisible = true;

                } else {
                    recVisible = false;
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void createShadow(Color color, BufferedImage shadow) {
        Graphics2D g2 = shadow.createGraphics();
        g2.setPaint(color);
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, 1, h);
        g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.DstIn);
        g2.setPaint(new GradientPaint(0, 0, new Color(0, 0, 0, 0f), 0, h,
                new Color(0.5f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.5f)));
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, 1, h);
        g2.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        if(recVisible){
        paintShadow(g,imgRed,shadowRed);
        } else {
        paintShadow(g,imgBlue,shadowBlue);
        }
    }

    private void paintShadow(Graphics g,BufferedImage img, BufferedImage shadow) {
        if (img == null || img.getWidth() != getWidth()
                || img.getHeight() != getHeight()) {
            img = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(),
                    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        }
        Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
        super.paint(g2);
        Rectangle bounds = getViewport().getVisibleRect();
        g2.scale(bounds.getWidth(), -1);
        int y = (getColumnHeader() == null) ? 0 : getColumnHeader().getHeight();
        g2.drawImage(shadow, bounds.x, -bounds.y - y - h, null);
        g2.scale(1, -1);
        g2.drawImage(shadow, bounds.x, bounds.y + bounds.height - h + y, null);
        g2.dispose();
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for code, but I search for dymanic changes, if 1st & last Row is visible in the JViewPort then (e.g.) Color.red, if isn't in visible then Color.red could be changed to the different color

Comment: hmmmm not, this image was from 2nd. update, looks like as extends JTable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051755/java-wait-cursor-display-problem/6060678#6060678 would be easiest as JScrollPane :-)

Comment: Hmm.  I just ran it again and looks like what you are asking for.   Please check to make sure you are running the right code.

Comment: yes I'm sure, because these methods never listening ChangeEvents

Comment: Take a look at the construtor of GradientViewPort in the 2nd version.