# Interchangeable JComponent skins for JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, skinning, jcomponent

I'm attempting to create a custom `JButton` that has interchangeable skin components. Using `CardLayout` as the switching mechanism, I'm having difficulty with the `JComponent` (i.e. skin component) laying flush across the `JButton`.

---

For instance,

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public final class SkinsDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI(){
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.add(new JSkinnableButton());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static final class JSkinnableButton extends JButton{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -5167346969674067012L;

        protected JSkinnableButton(){
            super();
            setLayout(new CardLayout()); // for interchangeability 
            add(new JSkinComponent(), "Skin");
        }
    }

    private static final class JSkinComponent extends JComponent{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 2172542865655802012L;

        protected JSkinComponent(){
            super();
            setOpaque(true);
            setLayout(new FlowLayout()); // need layout manager
            setBackground(Color.CYAN);
            add(new JLabel("Skin"));
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            Graphics gCopy = g.create();
            gCopy.setColor(getBackground());
            gCopy.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            gCopy.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

---

That's a really crude example, but I think it conveys my intentions clearly.

And this `JButton` will be listening for property change events from a domain object and will update it's display accordingly.

Comment: back from the ends, `1)` are you want to fill with Color.CYAN whole JButton `2)` by using LayoutManager, `3)` how much skins you want to.., `4)` skin depends of JButton Events ???

Comment: @mKorbel, I want the background of the `JComponent` to fill the entire `JButton` and by using the `CardLayout` manager, I want to be able to easily switch between 3 different skins, which are changed upon receiving a `PropertyChangeEvent`.

Comment: Why not just change the `Icon` or, less conveniently, the `ButtonUI`?

Comment: @trashgod that would be easy, I think that (@mre) knows that, maybe ??? basically ??? same question as I post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197261/jtable-how-to-change-background-color, change paint(), paintComponent at Runtime, without fileckering and another side effect from un-correct usage of CustomPaint for compound JComponent, to find the correct (and then) simple way, I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's space being taken up in your `JSkinnableButton` by the button's margin and border.

```
protected JSkinnableButton(){
    super();
    setLayout(new CardLayout()); // for interchangeability
    setMargin(new Insets(0,0,0,0));
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    add(new JSkinComponent(), "Skin");
}
```

Now, the border in particular, is a part of what makes a button look like a button, but I assume you've already got a plan for that...