# How to make a JFrame blurred in java?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlayer

In my java program, when the user clicks on a button in the main `JFrame` another `JFrame` becomes visible on top of the main frame. Now how to make the previous frame blurred? 
Exactly like the background in the image :

[image: Overlay blurring background]

Comment: @MadProgrammer I simply mean what you see in that image! (a manner that the contents of the frame are not in details....)

Comment: Uhm I dont get how this will be incorporated to a OS GUI. Because technically the top dialog would be sized to fit its contents and the frame behind will remain its current size. Using JFrame and JDialog would give this effect by default with modality (of course taking it that the JFrame is larger than the JDialog)

Comment: @DavidKroukamp `Using JFrame and JDialog would give this effect by default with modality` excuse me ?!!!!

Comment: Well except the blurring... is that what you want?

Comment: @DavidKroukamp if `blurring` means what you see in the image, so yes !

Comment: See also [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now how to make the previous frame blurred?

- have look at [JLayer(Java7) based on JXLayer(Java6)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html),
- similair effect is possible with [`GlassPane`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8715807/layering-multiple-glasspanes-in-a-root-container), or with [`JViewport`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197261/jtable-how-to-change-background-color) (not proper of ways, but good Swing GUI contains `JScrollPane` as 1st. `JComponent` in `JFrame` / `JDialog` / `JWindow`)

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you are coding using Java Swing, and the picture is the effect you want.

You would use a `JDialog` to create the top window, rather than a `JFrame`.  A `JDialog` is designed to be modal.  In other words, lock the `JFrame` until the `JDialog` is closed.

The default behavior of a `JDialog` is to not blur or darken the underlying `JFrame`.  In order to darken the underlying `JFrame`, you're going to have to paint a black image on the glass pane of the `JFrame`.

This [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) shows you how to manipulate the root panes of a `JFrame`.

Answer (score 1):

There is the `setOpacity(float opacity)` method that is available in `JFrame` (inherited from `Frame` actually).

Comment: Wait, `Frame` is from `java.awt`, isn't it? I thought the `java.awt` package wasn't available on Android?

Comment: @11684 I think the screenshot is just an example of the desired effect, it doesn't indicate that the OP is programming in Android.

Comment: Yes, that made me think already, but I thought there was a Android port of Swing maybe..

Comment: not related to what i want. look at the image another time, i don't want a transparent frame, i want a frame that its contents are not visible in details...

Comment: @11684 JFrame is in Swing, the question is about Swing, the screenshot is just an example.