# How to extends JViewport correctly?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jviewport

I am trying to design a class of endless coordinate board with a grid. I have extended a `JViewport` and it draws at initial position ok (inside `JScrollPane`). How to tell scroll pane that there are some space to scroll in any direction?

The following does not help

```
            JCoordinateViewport coordinate = new JCoordinateViewport();
            coordinate.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            //coordinate.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10000, 10000));

            JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane();
            //scroll.setViewportView(coordinate);
            scroll.setViewport(coordinate);
            scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            scroll.getVerticalScrollBar().setMinimum(-10000);
            scroll.getVerticalScrollBar().setMaximum(+10000);
            scroll.getHorizontalScrollBar().setMinimum(-10000);
            scroll.getHorizontalScrollBar().setMaximum(+10000);
```

**UPDATE**

Does anybody knows how JScrollPane determines scroll ranges from it's viewport?

**UPDATE2**

I found, that scrollbars appear t work if maximums and minimums are set after `setVisible` called.

But unfortunately, `paintConponent` does not called upon scroll.

Why?

**UPDATE3**

Although scroll bars work, they don't change viewport position.

Why?

Comment: Scrolling is based on the preferred size of the component added to the viewport of the scrollpane.

Comment: I have no component, I am extending `JViewport` and it's component is `null`.

Comment: Well a scrollpane was designed to display a component in its viewport, so that would be your problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
CoordinateViewport coordinate = new JCoordinateViewport(); coordinate.setBackground(Color.WHITE); //coordinate.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10000, 10000));

JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(); //scroll.setViewportView(coordinate);
scroll.setViewport(coordinate); 
scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS); 
scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS); 
scroll.getVerticalScrollBar().setMinimum(-10000); 
scroll.getVerticalScrollBar().setMaximum(+10000); 
scroll.getHorizontalScrollBar().setMinimum(-10000); 
scroll.getHorizontalScrollBar().setMaximum(+10000);
```

.

> The following does not help

- then issue should be only in the class with name `CoordinateViewport`
- for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about `JFrame`, `JScrollPane` and `JViewport`
- for reducing of flickering in the `JViewport` is required to set

  1. own `RepaintManager`
  2. and by using/with built_in methods in `JViewport`

  JViewport.setScrollMode(JViewport.BLIT_SCROLL_MODE); 
  JViewport.setScrollMode(JViewport.BACKINGSTORE_SCROLL_MODE); 
  JViewport.setScrollMode(JViewport.SIMPLE_SCROLL_MODE);
- please see [Passing current Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614972/passing-current-date) and [JTable how to change BackGround Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197261/jtable-how-to-change-background-color) as potential source for [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 2):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3518047/230513), painting on a `JViewport` appears to "stick" to the viewport, while painting on the underlying scrollable component slides beneath. Sizes are integral multiples of `TILE`: for demonstration purposes, the preferred size of the viewport is made smaller than the underlying panel; in practice, it's better to override [`getPreferredSize()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513). See also  [`ScrollAction`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7203419/230513), which auto-scrolls as the mouse hovers near any border.

[image]