# JTextPane fixed background image

Tags: java, css, swing, jtextpane

Dude, on package `foo.bar` I have got a `JTextPane` class(`MyJTextPane`), and an image `back.png`.
Now I would do something in CSS with my Text pane, I like to use the embedded `back.png` file as fixed-scroll, both horizontal and vertical center position.
There is no any surprise about the css which would be like this.

```
body { 
  background: url('back.png') no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

My question, is it possible at all to apply this property for `JTextPane` too? if yes, so how would I point out the embedded image resource here?
If no, is there another solution then?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do custom painting on the background of the JViewport:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class ViewportBackground
{
    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5, 30);
        textArea.setOpaque(false);

        JViewport viewport = new JViewport()
        {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
            {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                int w = this.getWidth();
                int h = this.getHeight();
                g.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 255, 50));
                g.fillRect(0, 0, w/2, h/2);
                g.setColor(new Color(255, 0, 0, 50));
                g.fillRect(w/2, 0, w, h/2);
                g.setColor(new Color(0, 255, 0, 50));
                g.fillRect(0, h/2, w, h/2);
            }
        };

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setViewport(viewport);
        scrollPane.setViewportView( textArea );

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( scrollPane );
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This example just paints a patterned background, buy you can easily use the `Graphics.drawImage(...)` method to paint an image for the background.

Comment: Very nice solution bro, so you mean this is the only way to have something like this?

Comment: +1 but I'd suggest to [setScrollMode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197261/jtable-how-to-change-background-color)