# Make HTML table inside JList cell as wide as the cell

Tags: java, html, jlist

I'm using HTML to style a cell inside JList -- it's a simple two-row table, where the second row has a non-default background. I want that row to span the whole width of the cell, instead of having it only as wide as the text inside it is.

Here's an example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();              
        String html = "<html>";
        html += "<style type=\"text/css\">"
                + "body { margin: 0px auto; }\n"
                + "td { padding: 0px; margin: 0px; }\n"
                + "</style>";
        html += "<body><table>";
        html += "<tr><td>line1</td></tr>";
        html += "<tr><td bgcolor=blue color=white>line2</td></tr>";
        html += "<body></table></html>";
        ArrayList<String> dataList = new ArrayList();
        dataList.add(html);
        JList list = new JList(dataList.toArray()); 
        frame.getContentPane().add(list);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);        
    }
}
```

"line2" has blue background, but only under the text. I want it to go all the way to the end of the window, essentially making the table (or row) width 100% of the cell width.

I tried placing "width:100%" in various places, with no effect. The only thing that worked was setting the td {width...} to a specific pixel width, but then I'll need a custom cell renderer to change that width every time the window/component is resized... and it seems like there must be a simple html/css-only solution to this problem.

Comment: Post your `SSCCE` that demonstrates the problem then maybe someone will be able to help.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my post with an example.

Comment: There seems to be a nice hole where all the documentation for using HTML in a JLabel should be. But, it really depends on how the renderer of the HTML is getting passed sizes. I'd be surprised if the default implementation signaled the HTML renderer every time the JLabel changed size. So... have fun with your custom renderer :)

Comment: I did end up finding the [CSS documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/CSS.html). I states that width is modelled but not rendered and that relative units are not supported unless noted next to the item in the list on the page I linked. I think font size is the only item it is supported with.

Comment: Thanks. Custom renderer it is, then. It shouldn't be too bad -- I'll only need a "table { width: " + list.getSize().width + "px" }" or something along those lines thrown in by the renderer, I believe.

Comment: If you're still implementing then this might be useful:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091816/displaying-large-jlist-formatted-as-html/20814652#20814652