# JTable Multiline cell Auto wrap

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Im developing Hospital Managment System Application using java, i have ICD-10 codes with a very long texts, i want to show them with jtable, but since the text is too long i need the JTable cell to wrap text as needed & change the hieght of that row as required.

is there any idea how to do that, or any other suggestions if there is.

Comment: Similar discussion: [How to wrap lines in a jtable cell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965023/how-to-wrap-lines-in-a-jtable-cell)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than clutter the table with wrapped text in each row, consider displaying the full text in an adjacent `JTextComponent` only for the selected row. Because [ICD-10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICD-10) is hierarchical in nature, also consider an outline view, as shown [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/4447/6692).