# How to implement multiple line text renderer in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, abstracttablemodel

I faced the same problem as mentioned in the following SO question [Wrap multiple lines in JTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965023/how-to-wrap-lines-in-a-jtable-cell). and I found [Multile cell rendered](http://blog.botunge.dk/post/2009/10/09/JTable-multiline-cell-renderer.aspx) to do that job. Now my problem is after implementing the cell renderer my cell is not showing wrapped data. I have custom tableModel and I am not sure how to call datavalidator on that model. Could anyone please suggest me.

My Table model:

```
public class KeywordTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(KeywordTableModel.class.getName());
    KeywordList keywordList ;

public KeywordTableModel(KeywordList keywordList){
    this.keywordList = keywordList;
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return keywordList.getKeywords().size();
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return keywordList.getTitles().length;
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TypeRec objectRec = (TypeRec) keywordList.getKeywords().elementAt(rowIndex);
    return objectRec.getColumnData(columnIndex);
}

@Override
public String getColumnName(int column){
    return keywordList.getTitles()[column];
}

public void setDataValidator(){

}

}
```

My cell renderer is :

```
/**
   * Multiline Table Cell Renderer.
   */
  public class MultiLineTableCellRenderer extends JTextArea 
    implements TableCellRenderer {
    /**
     * 
     */
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MultiLineTableCellRenderer.class.getName());
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private List<List<Integer>> rowColHeight = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

public MultiLineTableCellRenderer() {
  setLineWrap(true);
  setWrapStyleWord(true);
  setOpaque(true);
  logger.debug("inside multilinetablecellrenderer constructor");
}

public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
    JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
    int row, int column) {
    logger.debug("inside multilinetablecellrenderer renderer");
  if (isSelected) {
    setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
    setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
  } else {
    setForeground(table.getForeground());
    setBackground(table.getBackground());
  }
  setFont(table.getFont());
  if (hasFocus) {
    setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("Table.focusCellHighlightBorder"));
    if (table.isCellEditable(row, column)) {
      setForeground(UIManager.getColor("Table.focusCellForeground"));
      setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Table.focusCellBackground"));
    }
  } else {
    setBorder(new EmptyBorder(1, 2, 1, 2));
  }
  if (value != null) {
    setText(value.toString());
  } else {
    setText("");
  }
  adjustRowHeight(table, row, column);
  return this;
}

/**
 * Calculate the new preferred height for a given row, and sets the height on the table.
 */
private void adjustRowHeight(JTable table, int row, int column) {
  //The trick to get this to work properly is to set the width of the column to the
  //textarea. The reason for this is that getPreferredSize(), without a width tries
  //to place all the text in one line. By setting the size with the with of the column,
  //getPreferredSize() returnes the proper height which the row should have in
  //order to make room for the text.
  logger.debug("inside adjustRowheight method for adjusting the row height");
  int cWidth = table.getTableHeader().getColumnModel().getColumn(column).getWidth();
  setSize(new Dimension(cWidth, 1000));
  int prefH = getPreferredSize().height;
  while (rowColHeight.size() <= row) {
    rowColHeight.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(column));
  }
  List<Integer> colHeights = rowColHeight.get(row);
  while (colHeights.size() <= column) {
    colHeights.add(0);
  }
  colHeights.set(column, prefH);
  int maxH = prefH;
  for (Integer colHeight : colHeights) {
    if (colHeight > maxH) {
      maxH = colHeight;
    }
  }
  if (table.getRowHeight(row) != maxH) {
    table.setRowHeight(row, maxH);
  }
}
```

}

and I am setting my cell renderer as

```
     cnr_DATA.setDefaultRenderer(String.class, new MultiLineTableCellRenderer());
```

The program is still not wrapping data in multiple line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absent a complete example, I'm guessing you need to override `getColumnClass()` in your `TableModel` to return the same [type token](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/literals.html) that you specified in `setDefaultRenderer()`, i.e. `String.class`. Note that the `AbstractTableModel` implementation returns `Object.class` unconditionally.

Comment: @trashgod Thank you so much, your suggestion work perfectly. Thanks again

Comment: @trashgod one more question, so if we want to set the width of the column on the basis of their content, how can we achieve that.

Comment: See [*Setting and Changing Column Widths*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#width).